# Optional text in regex

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'trying to write a regex that matches an url with and without html, Itried this way but ots not working

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/my_url(\.html)$ /es/promo/my_url.html
```

It shoul work for `myurl` and `my_url.html` but it doesn't

Comment: `(\.html)?` will do

Comment: I though that but is not working

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written and tested as per shown samples. This will rewrite every non existing file and non existing directory to respective html in backend to be served. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my_url [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: But the redirection  I need  its for one url not for every url , has to redirect this url with and without .html

Comment: @a_cl, could you please try my edited rules and let me know then? how it goes.

Comment: @a_cl, could you please do let me know if my edited rules worked for you? In case of redirect you can use `R=301` in above with `L` too here, let me know.

Comment: @a_cl, could you please do let me know on this one?

Answer (score 0):

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es/promo/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:\.html?|/?)$ /es/promo/$1.html [L,NC,R=301]
```